# What programs can I use to see what traffic of mine a network admin can see?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, monitoring, packet

What programs can I use to see what traffic of mine a network admin can see?

Monitor incoming and outgoing network traffic at a the packet level, I want to make sure my VPN is working properly.

Answer (score 5):

[Wireshark will do that.](http://www.wireshark.org/) It's an open source packet sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

Old faithful - `tcpdump`.  This link gives some reasons why `tcpdump` MIGHT be a better choice than wireshark...

[Concern over running WireShark as root](https://superuser.com/questions/139206/concern-over-running-wireshark-as-root)

Comment: Just use tcpdump to capture the pcap file (-w file.pcap) and open it with wireshark running as a regular user.