# Concern over running Wireshark as root

Tags: root, wireshark

I started [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org) on my Ubuntu machine and discovered that there were no interfaces I could listen to. So I launched it as root. This gave me access to all the interfaces, but gave me a warning:

> Running Wireshark as user 'root' in group 'root'. This could be dangerous...

So, is it dangerous? Otherwise, how can I listen to the interfaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wireshark is quickly approaching [two million lines of code](http://www.wireshark.org/download/automated/sloccount.txt). You shouldn't run them as root for the same reasons that you shouldn't run Firefox, OpenOffice, GIMP, or any other similarly-sized application as root.

On Linux you don't need to be root to capture packets. You just need the CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW privileges. On most distributions this is [easy to get up and running](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/19/sniffing-wireshark-non-root-user/). Ubuntu doesn't do this by default yet, but it hopefully will [at some point in the future](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/14140/).

Answer (score 4):

According to [the official Wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges) you should not run it as root.

> Wireshark has implemented Privilege Separation which means that the Wireshark GUI (or the tshark CLI) can run as a normal user while the dumpcap capture utility runs as root. This can be achieved by installing dumpcap setuid root. The advantage of this solution is that while dumpcap is run as root the vast majority of Wireshark's code is run as a normal user (where it can do much less damage).

Instead, use root privileges to dump using `dumpcap` or `tcpdump` and then analyse using Wireshark.

Comment: Ah... but can harm come of using root privileges?

Comment: In general, yes/no. Better not to use root where you can get by without it. But if this is just your home machine and you're not going to bring down your office network/servers, fire away. 

In relation to wireshark, I think you'll be safe enough.

Comment: unless someone on your network is spewing packets specially crafted to exploit bugs in wireshark; then, using it as root is bad, bad news.

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark has a long history of security bugs in the disectors (the plugins which describe how to interpret various over-the-wire protocols). For that reason, it's safer to perform your captures with a simpler tool such as tcpdump, then use wireshark to interpret them as an unprivileged user.